# How to get SharePoint Online usage data per user

Tags: site-usage, audit-log-reports, analytics, m365

I'm looking for a way to seamless  and continiously consildate data for the below :

Intranet Usage

Page View

Unique Visitors

Time spen on sites

Search Queries - Most frequent searched keywords

Recently updated - Most recently updated content

I know the OOTB site usage analytics has got some of the above but i need the reporting per user level.

I'm open if there is an API i can connect to pull out the data and for example use Power BI to display it or even use a webpart to display in SharePoint

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you're going to get anything that collects usage data on an individual user level OOTB unless you willing to use a third party or custom solution. For search analytics I would check out Search and Intelligence https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/usage-reports